# How to fix an invalid random string to make it JSON valid

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

In Javascript, I need to "fix" a string, supposed to be JSON valid but may not be. The string has the following format (the unknown part is marked with "<INVALID_CHARS>"):

```
[
    { "key_1": "ok_data", "key_2": "something_valid <INVALID_CHARS>"},
    { "key_1": "ok_data", "key_2": "some_valid_value"}
]
```

"INVALID_CHARS" are chars which make the JSON.parse() function fail.
The errors are always localized on the "key_2" property of this array elements.

Note that these chars come from random binary data, and can thus be anything.

I would like to find the simplest solution, or at least one which is the least prone to errors.

I thought of replacing invalid characters, but there is also a problem with single backslash chars followed by a non special char, throwing an error too, or quote chars.
And I probably did not think of all the possible errors.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you like to remove or replace the invalid characters?

Comment: if `INVALID_CHARS` includes `"` or `", foo: "bar"` how are you to know where one value ends and the next begins?

Comment: Have you tried replacing all `"`s with `\"`?

Comment: That's part of the problem yes. A human eye would know how to fix it, because it sees the next valid object in the array.

Comment: I also need to remove invalid chars, but I don't know how to find the list of all of them. Those who throw the "invalid character" error in JSON.parse().

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not allowed to contain arbitrary binary data; it must be a sequence of valid Unicode codepoints. (Usually these are transmitted in UTF-8 encoding, but regardless, arbitrary binary data is not possible.) So if you want to include arbitrary binary data you'll need to figure out how to unambiguously encode it for transmission. If you don't encode it in some way, then you won't be able to reliably distinguish a byte which happens to have the same code as `"` from the `"` which terminates the string.

There are a number of possible encodings you might use for which standard libraries exist in most languages. One of the most commonly used is base-64.

Comment: I need to handle this erroneous data (at least temporarily) because the sender software is in an embedded device and can't be upgraded for now. :)

Comment: @lath: if you're lucky, there is some less unreliable signal that the string of arbitrary data is complete. For example, if the data really looks like your sample, it could be that you could use `"},\n` as a delimiter, which is a lot less likely to show up in random data. You could use that to extract and delete the binary data before parsing the json. Or you could reinsert the binary data, suitably encoded. Depends on your needs, really.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to clarify the problem as seems you described wide range of the issues here. If you have problem with parsing structure above you just need to check the syntactic integrity of the structure. For example this structure parses well

```js
let var1 = JSON.parse('[
   {
      "key_1":"ok_data",
      "key_2":"something_valid <INVALID_CHARS>"
   },
   {
      "key_1":"ok_data",
      "key_2":"some_valid_value"
   }
]');
```

In case if you need to replace <INVALID_CHARS> as binary data with json characters it's possible to encode <INVALID_CHARS> in base64 as it's the most reliable way. But I guess also problem not only to pack <INVALID_CHARS>  to base64 and problem is also architectural and you need to prepare value of `key_2` with valid part and invalid part. In this way, I would suggest separate (split) `key_2` on two substrings separate by " " - `"key_2": "something_valid <INVALID_CHARS>(can be omitted)"`.
Moreover, it's possible to use separate fields for string without error and a second for errors. Like this `"key_2_1": "something_valid", "key_2_2":<INVALID_CHARS>`

Another way is to look to using Multipart Form Data if it's possible, to transfer binary data